# node.js - Express: Sending parameters to res.render()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, response

I am in a situation where the node.js server will perform a res.render() with an html file.

The html file will contain some standard html stuff.

The thing is, the server will have to send that html file an array of links.

The html file will receive the response from the server (the array of links) and will create html elements with those links.

I know of this way to send parameters in Express:
res.render('file.ejs', {title:'Hello', value:'world!} );

How can i implement sending the array of links in node/express and how can the client html file process it?

Is the above line of code ideal for my situation?

Comment: Did you try implementing the above code? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I dont know how to pass the array using the previous code. That line passes only a text file, how can i pass an array? And how will the client ckde lroceas that array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this example explains very well how to implement your case

https://www.codementor.io/naeemshaikh27/node-with-express-and-ejs-du107lnk6

Look at the last bit of code:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){ 
  res.render('index',{users : [
            { name: 'John' },
            { name: 'Mike' },
            { name: 'Samantha' }
  ]});
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But how can i manipulate these values from client side?

Comment: I see you are using 'file.ejs' in your response target so you should be able to manipulate response data with javascript on client side when you get it. Did you try to handle data in file.ejs ? I assume you have ejs package installed in your npm packages, right?

Comment: I did manage to see the data from node from client side! Thank you very much! Now i am trying to take the strings i sent to the client, and have the client create buttons with theses strings.